# C# Parsing XML via LINQ to create custom object

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I know there are many questions on this very topic but none of the examples I've tried have worked for me.

I have an existing XML document that is constructed like so:

```
<root>
    <ElementA>
        <element1>sometext</element1>
        <element2>sometext</element2>
        <element3>sometext</element3>
    </ElementA>

    <ElementA>
        <element1>sometext</element1>
        <element2>sometext</element2>
        <element3>sometext</element3>
    </ElementA>

    <ElementB>
        <element1>sometext</element1>
        <element2>sometext</element2>
        <element3>sometext</element3>
        <element4>sometext</element4>
        <element5>sometext</element5>
    </ElementB>

    <ElementB>
        <element1>sometext</element1>
        <element2>sometext</element2>
        <element3>sometext</element3>
        <element4>sometext</element4>
        <element5>sometext</element5>
    </ElementB>

    <ElementC>
        <element1>sometext</element1>
        <element2>sometext</element3>
    </ElementC>

    <ElementC>
        <element1>sometext</element1>
        <element2>sometext</element2>
    </ElementC>
</root>
```

I need to find all the ElementA, B, and Cs and create a new object of type objA, etc. whose properties correspond to the respective element's child elements.  Below is example code that I've tried.

```
var doc = XElement.Load(filename);
var data = from ele in doc.Elements()
           where ele.Name.LocalName.Equals("ElementA")
           select new objA
           {
                name = ele.Element("element1").Value
                address = ele.Element("element2").Value
           };
```

But this throws a null exception error when I try iterating through "data" collection.  What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

You can get elements by its name using `Elements("tagName")`:

```
var data = from ele in doc.Elements("ElementA")
           select new objA
           {
               name = (string)ele.Element("element1"),
               address = (string)ele.Element("element2")
           };
```

You also should use `(string)XElementInstance` instead of `XElementInstance.Value`, to avoid `NullReferenceException` when element does not exist in XML.

Code pasted above returns 2 elements for your sample input data.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  "data" ends up null.  I had tried your solution previously but it seems like doc.Elements("ElementA") doesn't find ElementA.  That's why I had to use the "where ele.Name.LocalName.Equals()"

Comment: So your real data has to be incorrect. I've tested it with your sample one and works fine.

Comment: True, I am wondering if there is something wonky with this XML doc.  The example I gave is not the original data but represents the logical layout.  Unfortunately this particular XML file I am forced to work with.  I've successfully parsed if previously using foreach loops and switch/cases but it's very ugly.

Comment: The only think I have on my mind is a case, when your `ElementA` is not directly under `root` element. You should use `Descendants` instead of `Elements` when that is your case.

Comment: Does your real document have a namespace by any chance?

Comment: Yes it does.  And not the typical w3.org namespace.  Something else the original author came up with.

Comment: SO you have to use `XNamespace` within your query.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try.  My apologies for not mentioning that, as I assumed the namespace would automatically be detected since it's in the markup.